# Javascript AMCharts referencing graph via ID not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

With AMCharts it is possible to select single graphs to edit them via css. If you give the graph an id you should see the class selector

```
amcharts-graph-[id]
```

for example

```
<g transform="translate(0,0)" class="amcharts-graph-smoothedLine amcharts-graph-g1">
```

however this is not working always the same way and I don't see the difference. Can anyone help me?

To clarify I have here to examples with the exact same code. The first is showing the class (and you can refer to it via css) the second one is not.

1. offical Demo by AMCharts: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/intraday-data/
2. exactly the same Demo opened in codepen (by clicking edit on the first link and then open in codepen) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJoaNB

You see the difference when you inspect the element of the graph (the green line). The class attribute for the line is missing in the codepen example (and in all my tests on my server as well).

You see the difference even more if you copy and paste the exact same css code in both, the demo (by clicking edit) and the codepen example:
The first will ease-out the line, the second won't - but what is the difference?

```
#chartdiv {
    width   : 100%;
    height  : 500px;
}       

.amcharts-graph-g1 .amcharts-graph-stroke {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000%;
  -webkit-animation: css-effect 10s ease-out forwards;
      animation: css-effect 10s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes css-effect {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000%;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}
@keyframes css-effect {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000%;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about amCharts applying the class names with the id of the objects. What you missed is that it's not enabled by default.

To enable this feature, you need to set [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#addClassNames) to `true` in your chart config.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "addClassNames": true,
  // ...
} );
```

Here's the same demo, with the above applied, animation working as expected:

http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/89720c7ca5b05e8ad8cea239a6fec30e/

Comment: small little detail, but you're right, I missed it.